# Coding in x86 - compiler code generation

Tags: compiler-construction, x86

Is there a good reference for writing code in x86 assembly. I am writing a compiler and i am currently in the code-generation phase. The language i am implementing is Object Oriented. For example now i am having trouble writing assembly for class declarations, object layouts etc... is there any book or reference that covers this topic ?

Comment: Your question is a big vague.  There's should be no assembly involved for class declarations or object layouts.

Comment: Maybe you can read the [clang/llvm](http://llvm.org/) source code?  In my experience it's been very easy to understand.

Comment: What do you mean no assembly involved for class declarations. What if i have a class with multiple methods and fields? if i dont code the methods in assembly then where/when will the be declared if they are used later on ?

Comment: @MikeG:  Class declarations are the whole enchilada; code (that is, executable statements) within them is more pertinent to assembly generation.

Comment: This is pretty straight forward.  You can oop up to high heaven with your language but the cpu is completely agnostic of language design.  It just implements the same tired old instruction set that has been around for the past 34 years, nothing oopy about it.  The investment here is in your language compiler first, your code generator next.

Comment: OOP shouldn't exist anymore in the code generation stage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [architecture reference documentation](http://www.intel.com/products/processor/manuals/) is your best bet.

However, don't expect any help for class declarations or much for object layouts.  The language specification being compiled would have some of this, but the machine code generated for class declarations is very loosely coupled to the language, and is largely a choice of the implementer, not the CPU architecture.

Comment: Can you please be more specific, for example is there a reference that explains how method decelerations are translated into assembly etc ... that would be great

Comment: @MikeG:  Method declaration translation to code is not a CPU architecture issue, which is what the documents are for.  The job of a compiler writer is to create code which compiles source code into object code.  Since you have chosen the challenge of writing a compiler, we expect that you *already* understand how to generate parse trees from source and translate those into pseudo instructions (or real instructions) targeting a particular architecture.

Comment: @MikeG: As stated already, stuff like laying out stack frames; putting args on the stack for method calls; and how to layout fields, dispatch table pointers, etc. in memory objects, aren't tied to an instruction set. There's just a way of doing it. You should be looking into the Dragon Book.

Comment: @MikeG: Or "Modern Compiler Implementation in C/Java/ML"

Answer (score 0):

There can be "direct" and "useful" answers to your question and they are likely incompatible.

The direct answer is that you should combine architecture reference (see link in previous answer) with details of the exact assembler you selected for this - e.g. gas, nasm, yasm, fasm, masm[32], tasm, etc.; all they have references on instruction syntax, pseudoinstructions (as segmentation, memory allocation, etc.), implementation details, object file format...

The useful (jIMHO) answer is that duplicating of results of industry leaders, as GNU Compiler Collection, Microsoft Developer Studio, etc. requires thousands of man-years so this is quite weird way; instead you should reuse existing measures as much as possible. For example, to verify the concept of your language you can implement convertor to C code and support library for this. Or, write for a well-known virtual machine and its language as Java or C#. On advanced level, you can replace compiler frontend with your own one (as GCC and LLVM allow) and reuse their code generating backends which are well written and tuned for multiple targets.

I quite doubt you are designing something that can't be converted to C and support library calls. The intermediate code shan't be fine looking, it shall just work.

If you still want to do sunset manually, please edit the question with more details on target platform (Windows/Linux/etc., 16- 32- or 64-bit...)